# Вывод имени разными цветами

Tags: php

я делаю так :

```
if($_SESSION['level'] == 1) {
echo "[.$row['date'].]<font color="#ff0000">.$row['username'].</font>.$row['message'].";
}

else {
  echo "[".$row['date']."]".$row['username']."  : ".$row['message'];}
}
```

Но эффекта нет, подскажите пожалуйста ошибку 
А вот сам чат:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout("window.location.reload()",10000);//Обновление раз в 5 секунд
</script>
<?php
session_start();
$db = mysql_connect("")or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("")or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

?>

<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
border-color: #CCCCFF/*верхний цвет*/ #CCCCFF/*правый цвет*/ #CCCCFF/*нижний цвет*/ #CCCCFF/*левый цвет*/;
border-style:
border-width: 1px/*в.г*/ 2px/*п.г*/ 4px/*н.г*/ 3px/*л.г*/;
background-color: #CCCCFF;

text-align: center;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div align="left">
<?php

if($_SESSION['level'] == 1) { 
echo $row['date'] . '<font color="#ff0000">' . $row['username'] . '</font>' . $row['message'];
}
else
{
  echo $row['date'] . $row['username'] .  ':' . $row['message'];
}

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Судя потому,как вывод должен быть в любом случае, думаю, запрос к БД некорректно осуществляется или до условия if() стоит еще другое условия.

Comment: Это вы специально пустыми оставили кавычки, или так было?

    $db = mysql_connect("")or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("")or die(mysql_error());

И потом у вас логика неправильная, вы 50 раз выводите 

    <html>...</html>

и все что в нем есть...

Comment: Ну тогда понятно, в таком случае недостает "}" фигурнйо скобки в конце условия 
    
    if(){
      ....
    } else{
      ....
    }
    } - вот этой скобки не хватает - она закрывает цыкл WHILE. 

и условие цыкла надо опустить до уровня IF, чтобы 50 раз не повторять код тела страницы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ**

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $db = mysql_connect("")or die(mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db("")or die(mysql_error());
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50");
?>

<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   body{
    border-color: #CCCCFF/*верхний цвет*/ #CCCCFF/*правый цвет*/ #CCCCFF/*нижний   цвет*/ #CCCCFF/*левый цвет*/;
    border-style:
    border-width: 1px/*в.г*/ 2px/*п.г*/ 4px/*н.г*/ 3px/*л.г*/;
    background-color: #CCCCFF;
    text-align: center;
   }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout("window.location.reload()",10000);//Обновление раз в 5 секунд
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div align="left">
 <?php
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if($_SESSION['level'] == 1) { 
      echo "[".$row['date']."]" . "<font color=\"#ff0000\">" . $row['username'] . "</font>" . " :" . $row['message'];
    }else{
      echo "[".$row['date']."]". $row['username'] .  " :" . $row['message'];
    }
   }
  ?>
 </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: нет, не показывает

Comment: С чего бы?

Comment: тебе бан!!!

Comment: @Fatahan - great job ^^

Comment: спасибо Алекс  ^^ - НЕ НАДО БАН! я учу человека делать Бэкапы :DDD

Comment: лучше сейчас чем потом :P

Comment: Учить надо другими способами, не причиняя вреда. А такое отношение к новичкам, 99 процентов просто не поймут.

Comment: я тоже новичок поэтому: 
1) мне пофиг на бан ^^
2) учу как могу :DDDD

Comment: @Fatahan ты то хоть бэки сделал, а-то человек трудился, жалко)

Comment: Ну, что сказать  - человек самоутвердился. @Fatahan  распирает от счастья да?

Comment: ДАААААА...я тут пляшу весь...троль во мне все сильней просыпается :DDDDDDDD PS. Сделал бэк...

Comment: Для меня больная тема)), у меня сейчас винт восстанавливается (3 месяца работы), а я только-только зеркалирование настроил, данные не успел перенести(. А вообще надо SMART пользоваться в довесок к бэку.

Comment: @Fatahan +60 =) А то мне че-то лень было)

Comment: @sh4dow Спасибо :) Я всегда рад - если надо обращайтесь...

Answer (score 1):

Слегка не корректно...Особенно если уровней много. Тут будет лучше применить конструкцию SwitchCase

Насчёт самой записи попробуйте :

```
echo $row['date'] . '<font color="#ff0000">' . $row['username'] . '</font>' . $row['message'];
```

Если что...То вы просто поставили в кавычках другие кавычки...Это не правильно...Поэтому они должны либо экранироваться знаками \ (Пример : \" текст\") либо должны ставится одинарные кавычки '' (Последний вариант может быть применён только с текстом и HTML и переменные в одинарных кавычках не выводятся.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_SESSION['level'] == 1) { 
echo $row['date'] . '<font color="#ff0000">' . $row['username'] . '</font>' . $row['message'];
}
else
{
  echo $row['date'] . $row['username'] .  ':' . $row['message'];
}
```

Comment: нет, не выводит, вот блин =)